# Use Google Places API to only retrieve a place type that is shown on Places webpage

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get a list of tobacco shops in Los Angeles but want to be very specific on the type. On the Places Webpage underneath the name of the place there is the reviews it has and the type of place it is. How can I write the textsearch url to only retrieve the ones that say 'Tobacco Shop'.

[this is what I want from places webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJqwt.jpg)

Right now I am using the textsearch url to do this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=tobacco%20shops%20in%20Los%20Angeles&key=API_KEY but don't know how to fix it to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is *mostly* doable with the Places API, with some caveats.

First, **searching** by places a (single) specific type is limited to the types in [Table 1: Place types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table1).

Second, Places API only **shows** those types plus the types in [Table 2: Additional types returned by the Places service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types#table2).

That said, you *can* search for any arbitrary string using [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text), and searching by the name of a more specific type of business is bound to return *mostly* businesses of that type.

What your screenshot highlights is also not currently available in the Places API; there is a (very popular) feature requests for it: [Detailed / primary place types (as seen on Google Maps)](https://issuetracker.google.com/35822953).